# Exchange, Public Folders and Mass Permission Changes

Tags: exchange, public-folders

Does anyone remember the tool that you used to be able to use to change many (1000s) of permissions on Exchange Public folders?

I think it might have come in some Exchange Resource Kit or maybe it was standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is PFAdmin.  It will check the permissions and correct them if they are messed up.  I'm not sure if it works on Exchange 2007 though.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2004/11/05/252979.aspx) is a great list of the public folder tools available.  You are probably thinking of PFadmin and outlook folders